How to include referenced projects
I have a solution with 4 projects inside. One of them we pack as a Nuget package, the others are just some common code shared between the projects. We want to publish the package but we do not want to publish a separate packages for every dependent project.
I tried following this tutorial, and I took the .csproj approach.
Here is what I have in the .csproj file on the project that I pack:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Title>LookupListCache</Title>
    <Authors>Yulian Dimitrov</Authors>
    <Description>This package contains everything for setting up a LookupListCache. Please configure LookupListCache connection string.</Description>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>
        Some release notes
    </PackageReleaseNotes>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Version>9.0.0-pg-03</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>9.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>9.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EFCore.NamingConventions" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="LEXolutionServiceBus" Version="1.5.175.63106" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LookupListCache.Common\LookupListCache.Common.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />

    <ProjectReference Include="..\LookupListCache.Migrations.CamelCase\LookupListCache.Migrations.CamelCase.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />

    <ProjectReference Include="..\LookupListCache.Migrations.SnakeCase\LookupListCache.Migrations.SnakeCase.csproj" PrivateAssets="All"/>

  </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="BuildOnlySettings;ResolveReferences">
        <ItemGroup>
            <!-- Filter out unnecessary files -->
            <_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'All'))"/>
        </ItemGroup>

        <!-- Print batches for debug purposes -->
        <Message Text="Batch for .nupkg: ReferenceCopyLocalPaths = @(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths), ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory) Filename = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename) Extension = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)" Importance="High" Condition="'@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)' != ''" />

        <ItemGroup>
            <!-- Add file to package with consideration of sub folder. If empty, the root folder is chosen. -->
            <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" TargetPath="%(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)"/>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>

When I try to pack the LookupListCache project I got the LookupListCache.9.0.0-pg-03.nupkg file, and in it's lib folder inside it has the 3 referenced .dll files:

In the .LookupListCache.nuspec file I have:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>LookupListCache</id>
    <version>9.0.0-pg-03</version>
    <title>LookupListCache</title>
    <authors>Yulian Dimitrov</authors>
    <description>This package contains everything for setting up a LookupListCache. Please configure LookupListCache connection string.</description>
    <releaseNotes>Some release notes</releaseNotes>
    <repository type="git" commit="5f74f5b8b658ff9995b648a3c09e5bd09b263515" />
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net8.0">
        <dependency id="AutoMapper" version="13.0.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="EFCore.NamingConventions" version="8.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" version="11.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Hangfire.Core" version="1.8.6" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="LEXolutionServiceBus" version="1.5.175.63106" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="8.0.8" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="8.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="8.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" version="8.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="8.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="8.0.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" version="8.0.8" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>

And when I try to install this package in other solution it says that it cant find the nuget packages:
NU1101: Unable to find package LookupListCache.Common. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Local, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org, standard_pde
NU1101: Unable to find package LookupListCache.Migrations.CamelCase. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Local, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org, standard_pde
NU1101: Unable to find package LookupListCache.Migrations.SnakeCase. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Local, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org, standard_pde

Is there a way that I can pack this project without the need to create separate nuget packages for the rest of the referenced projects?
